# Where does mongochef store its license file on osx?

Tags: osx-yosemite

Where does mongochef store its license file on osx? I'd like to clear it from my system and do a fresh install, preferably without reformatting my computer :)

In fact, I've been having a bit of trouble understanding where all the various files for any program seem to go, so any guidance on that would also be gladly consumed.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to reset the status of your trial and convert to a non-commercial license or the other way around? Get in touch with us via support@3t.io or http://3t.io/feedback and we'll help you out!

In general, we are working on putting all files in one place. In the near future you'll find everything in the .3T directory in your home (~) directory.

Comment: I put the license I bought on my personal computer and was hoping to move it to my work computer while letting me freely use mongochef for personal use at home.

Comment: The license can be used on all computers you own so you don't have to move it. If you still prefered to remove the it from your personal computer, then please get in touch with us via support@3t.io or http://3t.io/feedback